# Mysql Java Statement Error

Tags: java, database

Thats my code. My problem is 'ifade' named variable gives error. Sorry for my bad english. 
This screenshot:https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0sihq4w0q0a2n6/Screenshot%202014-08-31%2019.17.19.png?dl=0
[All of my code](http://pastebin.com/tFtYNTFA)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection baglanti = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(

    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iscikayit", "root", "");

    ifade = baglanti.createStatement();
    tc = textField.getText();
    ad = textField_1.getText();
    soyad = textField_2.getText();
    telno = textField_3.getText();
    eposta = textField_4.getText();
    egitim = comboBox.getName();
    adres = textArea.getText();
    cinsiyet = comboBox_2.getName();
    askerlik = comboBox_1.getName();
    ehliyet = comboBox_3.getName();
    ifade.executeUpdate("insert into isci(tc,ad,soyad,telno,eposta,egitim,adres,cinsiyet,askerlik,ehliyet)"
            +

            " values('"
            + tc
            + "','"
            + ad
            + "','"
            + soyad
            + "','"
            + telno
            + "','"
            + eposta
            + "','"
            + egitim
            + "','"
            + adres
            + "','"
            + cinsiyet
            + "','"
            + askerlik
            + "','"
            + ehliyet + ")");

}
```

});

Comment: Please attach a full stacktrace so we can more easily help you

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injection. Also: create a new each time `actionPerformed` is called is a *really* bad idea. Especially because you don't seem to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the look of the code and without an actual error to help, it looks like you are missing a comma at after ehliyet. Should be:

```
+ ehliyet + "')");
```

**EDIT**:
After looking at the screenshot, I think you are importing the wrong classes. Make sure you are using

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection baglanti = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iscikayit", "root", "");

        Statement ifade = baglanti.createStatement();
        String tc = textField.getText();
        String ad = textField_1.getText();
        String soyad = textField_2.getText();
        String telno = textField_3.getText();
        String eposta = textField_4.getText();
        String egitim = comboBox.getName();
        String adres = textArea.getText();
        String cinsiyet = comboBox_2.getName();
        String askerlik = comboBox_1.getName();
        String ehliyet = comboBox_3.getName();
        ifade.executeUpdate("insert into isci(tc,ad,soyad,telno,eposta,egitim,adres,cinsiyet,askerlik,ehliyet)"
                +
                " values('"
                + tc
                + "','"
                + ad
                + "','"
                + soyad
                + "','"
                + telno
                + "','"
                + eposta
                + "','"
                + egitim
                + "','"
                + adres
                + "','"
                + cinsiyet
                + "','"
                + askerlik
                + "','"
                + ehliyet + "')");
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**
It looks like you are trying to use cm.mysql.jdbc.Statement, but Connect.getStatement returns a java.sql.Statement, so you need to cast it if you want to use com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.

Comment: My problem is starting line "ifade".

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0sihq4w0q0a2n6/Screenshot%202014-08-31%2019.17.19.png?dl=0

Comment: It is not running correctly. Can you edit my code for me? I want write data to database.My table screenshot:https://www.dropbox.com/s/lagy7s5pb25bp7n/Screenshot%202014-08-31%2019.51.52.png?dl=0

Comment: If you use `import java.sql.Connection;` and `import java.sql.Statement;` instead of `import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection` and `import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement`, then you should be ok.

Like so http://pastebin.com/KQrZSGhB

Comment: On my machine in IntelliJ, this is working fine. Added try/catch and made variables final as they weren't in your code: http://pastebin.com/Qr3ndxAv

Comment: It is running.Thank you so much.